# Leaflet: How can I veto turning on an overlay layer?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

My leaflet app has two overlay layers. One of them has a lot of data, so that if the user selects it when not zoomed in pretty far, there is too much data to display without severely impacting the performance of the app (and the data is not useful at wide zoom levels anyway).

So when the user selects the layer in the layer control, the app checks how much data would be displayed at that zoom level. If it's beyond a certain threshold, an alert is given that they need to zoom in more to turn on that layer. The app has essentially vetoed the layer selection, but there seems to be no way to uncheck the checkbox input so that the UI is in sync with the internal state of the app wrt the activation of that layer.

I can programmatically remove the layer altogether, but I don't see any way to uncheck the checkbox input for the layer. Even a brute force approach by getting the layer control HTML container and walking the DOM doesn't seem to be feasible, as there are no IDs or unique attribute values that I can use to get a reference to the checkbox for the desired layer. I also tried removing the layer and re-adding it, but it comes back still checked.

Is there a way to programmatically uncheck the layer checkbox?

EDIT: Here's how I'm creating the overlay layer:

```
baseMaps = ...
map = ...
myBaseLayer = ...
myOverlayLayer = L.featureGroup();
myOverlayLayer.id = "theId";
let overlayMaps = {
    "Base Objects": myBaseLayer,
    "Overlay Layer": myOverlayLater
}

L.controlLayer.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmatically removing / adding your layer from/to map should automatically untick/tick the checkbox in the default Leaflet Layers Control.

What you describe sounds to need usage of minZoom option on your overlay layer. If I remember correctly it should also automatically reflect in the Layers Control when the layer is removed due to minZoom threshold.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you be more specific about how I would set minZoom on my  overlay layer? I updated the question to show how I'm creating and setting the overlay layer. I can't see anything in the API for setting a minZoom option, at least in the way I' creating the overlay layer.

Comment: Hum indeed the minZoom option is only for Grid/Tile Layer, whereas you have a Feature Group. Then you have to fallback to removing from / adding to map on "zoomend" event. And to zoom in on "overlayadd" event.

Comment: I got it to work by removing/adding the layer. The problem was I wasn't re-creating the layer when I did that, just removing and adding the object returned from L.featureGroup(). Now I remove that object from the layer control, get a new instance of the layer and add that back to the control, and that works. So I don't need to do that on zoomend (forcing a zoom-in on overlayadd would have been undesirable). I do it in the overlayadd listener when I want to veto the addition of the layer, and the checkbox is unchecked.